# Facebook Pixel and OpenCart 2.2

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, opencart

Hello all :) I've came across the following problem and I would need some help. I'm trying to install the facebook pixel in my online store. I'm using OpenCart 2.2. I've put the base pixel code in the header using the google analytics module. I've put the standard events on the correct pages. Downloaded and installed the "Facebook Pixel Helper" app for Google Chrome and everything is working perfectly. :) The problem comes with the event for purchase. This is the event code:

```
<script>
  fbq('track', 'Purchase', {value: 0.00, currency: 'BGN'});
</script>
```

Here "value" is static and always is "0.00".. How to make it fetch the price of the product? Tried a couple of options using the tokens "$price", "$product['price']", "$text_price" as those are the tokens for the price in OpenCart, but none of these works.. I'm thinking of a solution with JavaScript and record the actual price in a value above the facebook event code and using this value for the price, but I'm not sure how to do this. Is there other solution to this?
Thanks in advance for all the help!!

Best regards,
Tsvetko Krastev

Answer (score 0):

To get price of any product, use this

```
$this->load->model('catalog/product');
$product_id = 21 // assume that product id is 21
$product_info = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($product_id); // get product info
$data['price'] = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($product_info['price'], $product_info['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')), $this->session->data['currency']);
```

Now set this price whatever you want.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! :) I tried it, but no success.. The header in OpenCart is the same for every page, but the facebook event code should be placed individually on the pages depending on what you are tracking. So the event code should be in page "success.tpl", so it would collect data only when that page is visited.
So I tried adding the first part in the header, and the event code only in success.tpl, but no joy.. Tried putting them both in success.tpl and it sends 0.00 as price.

Comment: I update my answer. Please try this way and let me know.